# Multiple references to the same footnote in a Google doc

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

How do I add multiple references to the same footnote in Google Docs?

When adding footnotes the usual way (selecting `Insert > Footnote` in the menu), a new footnote is created every time. But if I want to refer to the same written explanation or bibliographical source multiple times, there's seemingly no way to do that.

---

**Example** (what I want to achieve)

- How do supplier evaluations<sup>1</sup> typically happen?
- What criteria for selection, evaluation og re-evaluations<sup>1</sup> are typically used?

... *rest of page* ...

<sup>1</sup> ISO 9001:2008: 7.4.1 Purchasing Process

---

While I understand this is "bad style" ([productforums.google.com...](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/yjLBJCgIG2w)) I think this way of referencing makes it obvious to the reader that the same source is being referenced multiple times, and she/he doesn't have to move attention down to the bottom of the page in order to see what is referenced every time.

Comment: I take it from the responses that this is not possible.

Comment: 2020 Update: Looks possible, despite bad style from darnalisa's answer below for me. Very useful for table/cell annotation.

Comment: @LamChau can you tell us how.

Answer (score 4):

To keep using the automatic footnote option, manually add 'a' to the first ref. using the superscript function under the format tab. Then manually label the second ref.  '1b'. This way your footnotes will not be out of sequence when you continue to use the auto footnote tool.

Comment: If I need to add, say, "3-7" that does will not work...if, say, the 4, 5, 6th footnotes weren't already added somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

Command (for Macs), "." to add another superscript, then type the number of the footnote you're referencing. warning, the number will not change with the original footnote.

For example:

```
blah blah blah.1

blah blah.1

1 blah
```

But if you add another footnote before it (changing the number) it will not change with it (so just change it):

```
blah blah.1
blah blah blah.2

blah blah.1

1 blah
2 blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you have to manually do it. Just click or put your curser where you want to repeat the endnote number then go to format. There should be a subscript option, just click on it and then you can type any number in.